# How do I disable the update button on View Cart for specific product categories in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I have an OpenCart site and would like to disable the update button in the View Cart page for products belonging to a specific category. If the products don't belong to the category, the update button will be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a column in the database then add supporting code to the admin/controller, admin/template, catalog/controller, catalog/view/theme/yourtemplate. Then you can wrap the view cart button in your catalog/view/theme/yourtemplate/product/product.tpl with a PHP IF exists statement.

Just an example. Good luck!

Comment: alternatively, if you don't care to be clean about it, you can just use an existing field like JAN, EAN, UPC, etc and make call it from your controller file and wrap the button with an if statement corresponding to the variable and field you decided to use

Comment: I took a similar approach, and got it to work. Thanks!